# Do functions that decay at $\pm \infty$ eventually become a constant $0$ function?

Tags: integration, functions

If a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ decays at $\pm \infty$, does that mean it will have 'died out' before reaching $\pm \infty$ i.e

$f=0$ for $x\geq a$ for some $a>0$ and

$f=0$ for $x\leq b$ for some $b<0$

as the function can never take on a value at $\pm \infty$

Comment: what about $e^{-x^2}\sin x?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generally means that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$, but $f$ never needs to be equal to $0$.

Consider for instance $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$. This function is always strictly positive, but its value gets smaller and smaller as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ (see picture below).

[image: Graph of $f$]

Comment: Am i correct in saying that the area under the curve is finite (= $\pi$)?    Bizzarre as this may seem

Comment: For this curve it is correct, but in general the fact that $f$ decays at $\pm\infty$ is not sufficient to conclude integrability (which is what it means when you say that the area under the curve is finite). For example, the area under the curve $f(x)=1/(1+|x|)$ is *not* finite.